# How can I plot a gradient line in HTML canvas?

Tags: html, canvas

I am trying to draw a line which is a gradient. How is that possible in canvas?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this : http://diveintohtml5.org/canvas.html#gradients ?

Comment: yes. I wanted to apply it to a line and I figured out the ctx.strokeStyle works.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Yes. Example:

```
// linear gradient from start to end of line
var grad= ctx.createLinearGradient(50, 50, 150, 150);
grad.addColorStop(0, "red");
grad.addColorStop(1, "green");

ctx.strokeStyle = grad;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(50,50);
ctx.lineTo(150,150);

ctx.stroke();
```

See it in action here:

http://jsfiddle.net/9bMPD/

Comment: Just a note that the gradient is not follow the circle but is linear. It will not be uniformly distributed. You make it more uniform by splitting the circle into several parts and creating separate gradient for each part.